# Why does my network drive (Win XP) keep disappearing from my Mac notebook?

Tags: macos, mac, network-shares

I have managed to share my server drives of my Win XP and browse from my Mac notebook, but when I have some server restart, I cannot get it reestablished with the 'remembered' settings.

Is this a known problem?

Comment: Are you trying to have the share re-mounted when the WinXP server comes back up?

Comment: Eric, my question appears to be misleading (see my comment below to Jon).  BTW - did you tag it as "belongs-on-superuser"?? If so, why, I thought this was appropriate here since it is network / client-server question.  I have only briefly visited super-user and I thought that was more 'power' questions of a general nature.  Help me understand so I can be a better serverfault citizen.
-Sincerely mobibob

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the network drive to your login items in the accounts section of the System preferences - it won't reconnect if you don't.

Comment: Hi Jon,  Upon reading your answer and re-reading my question, my question is not what I meant to ask.  I actually have not had problem at the macbook side rebooting and remembering my network places.  I put them in the Finder navigation panel.  What I meant to ask about is when the server reboots.  I will credit you with this answer as that was a feature I did not now about and it is a solution to my (unintended question).  I will post a new question for what I originally was looking for.  -thanks mobibob

Comment: Yikes - if your server is re-booting enough to cause a problem - you have bigger problems!

Snow Leopard handles server disconnects a lot better than Leopard - you might consider upgrading.

Comment: Well if it's a Windows XP "Server" reboots aren't really all that unexpected..